# The allocation has failed

Tags: virtual-machine, size, cluster-computing, allocation, capacity

the VM does not start and I get this error.

I also tried to resize the VM, but the problem is not solved.

Error: Allocation failed. The available capacity is not sufficient for the virtual machine size required in this area.

any idea??

my client can't work

Comment: I solved it, seeing which size was available in Northern Europe and I went from a standard D3 v2 to a DS3 v2

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please be advised that your question is extremely broad and unclear. Please read the [how to ask guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and take your time editing the question.

Comment: In this case: great! Please share more detail on how you solved it in a dedicated answer to this question! :)